# SQL - Combining Two Select Statements

Tags: sql

Somewhat new to the site, and I am still very new to SQL, and I am attempting to write a query for RedPrairie (A warehouse management system) in Server Command Operations. I found out I had access, to write queries and one of the custom DDA's is inefficient because it combines staged Handling Units and Staged Weight, but it doesn't segregate what is already planned for outbound and what is not.

For that reason, I am trying to come up with a query and am having much trouble combining queries. My query will be using the same tables, but I want it to separate the columns of what is planned versus what is unplanned. I have attempted to the following:

```
[SELECT addr.host_ext_id destination,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT iv.lodnum)
       FROM inventory_view iv,
            locmst lm,
            aremst am,
            shipment_line sl,
            shipment sh,
            adrmst addr,
            uc_invlod uil,
            uc_load_grp ulg
      WHERE lm.wh_id = 'MWCCD'
                AND iv.lodnum=uil.lodnum
                AND am.arecod = lm.arecod
                AND am.wh_id = lm.wh_id
                AND lm.stoloc = iv.stoloc
                AND lm.wh_id = iv.wh_id
                AND addr.host_ext_id = ulg.dest_code
                AND ulg.client_id IS NOT NULL
                AND addr.adr_id = sh.rt_adr_id
                AND sl.ship_line_id = iv.ship_line_id
                AND sh.ship_id = sl.ship_id
                AND sh.stop_id IS NULL
                AND am.fwiflg = 1
                AND am.stgflg = 1) AS Unplanned_Hu,
    (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT uil.weight_kg) 
       FROM inventory_view iv,
            locmst lm,
            aremst am,
            shipment_line sl,
            shipment sh,
            adrmst addr,
            uc_invlod uil,
            uc_load_grp ulg
      WHERE lm.wh_id = 'MWCCD'
            AND iv.lodnum=uil.lodnum
            AND am.arecod = lm.arecod
            AND am.wh_id = lm.wh_id
            AND lm.stoloc = iv.stoloc
            AND lm.wh_id = iv.wh_id
            AND addr.host_ext_id = ulg.dest_code
            AND ulg.client_id IS NOT NULL
            AND addr.adr_id = sh.rt_adr_id
            AND sl.ship_line_id = iv.ship_line_id
            AND sh.ship_id = sl.ship_id
            AND sh.stop_id IS NULL
            AND am.fwiflg = 1
            AND am.stgflg = 1) AS Unplanned_Weight_KG, 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT iv.lodnum)
       FROM inventory_view iv,
            locmst lm,
            aremst am,
            shipment_line sl,
            shipment sh,
            adrmst addr,
            uc_invlod uil,
            uc_load_grp ulg
       WHERE lm.wh_id = 'MWCCD'
                    AND iv.lodnum=uil.lodnum
                    AND am.arecod = lm.arecod
                    AND am.wh_id = lm.wh_id
                    AND lm.stoloc = iv.stoloc
                    AND lm.wh_id = iv.wh_id
                    AND addr.host_ext_id = ulg.dest_code
                    AND ulg.client_id IS NOT NULL
                    AND addr.adr_id = sh.rt_adr_id
                    AND sl.ship_line_id = iv.ship_line_id
                    AND sh.ship_id = sl.ship_id
                    AND sh.stop_id IS NOT NULL
                    AND am.fwiflg = 1
                    AND am.stgflg = 1) AS Planned_HU,
    (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT uil.weight_kg)
       FROM inventory_view iv,
            locmst lm,
            aremst am,
            shipment_line sl,
            shipment sh,
            adrmst addr,
            uc_invlod uil,
            uc_load_grp ulg 
      WHERE lm.wh_id = 'MWCCD'
                AND iv.lodnum=uil.lodnum
                AND am.arecod = lm.arecod
                AND am.wh_id = lm.wh_id
                AND lm.stoloc = iv.stoloc
                AND lm.wh_id = iv.wh_id
                AND addr.host_ext_id = ulg.dest_code
                AND ulg.client_id IS NOT NULL
                AND addr.adr_id = sh.rt_adr_id
                AND sl.ship_line_id = iv.ship_line_id
                AND sh.ship_id = sl.ship_id
                AND sh.stop_id IS NOT NULL
                AND am.fwiflg = 1
                AND am.stgflg = 1) AS Planned_Weight_KG
 FROM inventory_view iv,
    locmst lm,
    aremst am,
    shipment_line sl,
    shipment sh,
    adrmst addr,
    uc_invlod uil,
    uc_load_grp ulg        
 WHERE lm.wh_id = 'MWCCD'
        AND iv.lodnum=uil.lodnum
        AND am.arecod = lm.arecod
        AND am.wh_id = lm.wh_id
        AND lm.stoloc = iv.stoloc
        AND lm.wh_id = iv.wh_id
        AND addr.host_ext_id = ulg.dest_code
        AND ulg.client_id IS NOT NULL
        AND addr.adr_id = sh.rt_adr_id
        AND sl.ship_line_id = iv.ship_line_id
        AND sh.ship_id = sl.ship_id
        AND am.fwiflg = 1
        AND am.stgflg = 1
GROUP BY addr.host_ext_id]
```

The problem with this is that although it separates the columns just the way I want, it is calculating it incorrectly regardless of the addr.host_ext_id. The number of Planned/Unplanned HUs and Weight is supposed to be unique for each addr.host_ext_id.

Any assistance and time spent with this would be highly appreciated! Also, I wanted to note that I did try to do it much simpler by using a UNION ALL, and it kept combining the columns together.

Comment: My first assistance would be to insist that you rewrite the query using explicit `join` syntax.  If you are learning SQL, there is a simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: Excellent. I will research and rewrite. Not comfortable with joins just yet!

Answer (score 1):

Change alias in main query for `adrmst` table to something different what is used in subqueries, for example to `addr1`. Then you can connect `addr1.host_ext_id` with each subqueries `addr.host_ext_id` by adding to each subquery condition:

```
  AND addr.host_ext_id = addr1.host_ext_id
```

I think this correction must help.

Also consider to rewrite query using `JOIN` syntax as Gordon Linoff suggests. This makes it more readable.

Comment: Wow, actually that was it. That's crazy! Now they are the unique numbers that I was looking for. Thank you so very much!